# Android - RenderScript - Performance drop in SDK 21

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I'm developing a project which requires complex Photoshop type blend effects. I am using custom `RenderScript` scripts to solve this.

I've been testing it on a `Samsung Galaxy S4` device running **Kitkat**, and everything works great and very quickly.

I then tried testing it on a **Nexus 5** running **Lollipop**, and I noticed a sudden drop in performance.

I started timing separate sections in the code to see which parts slow down, and came up with this:

```
Allocation.createFromBitmap
- Runtime on Kitkat - ~5-10 millisec
- Runtime on Lollipop - ~100-150 millisec

mRenderScript.destory()
- Runtime on Kitkat - ~1-3 millisec
- Runtime on Lollipop - ~60-100 millisec
```

I'm curious as to why there is a sudden drop in performance when creating `Allocation` objects and destroying `RenderScript` objects on a device which should be stronger, and on an OS which should be more advanced.

Is there anything I can do specific to API 21 OS's which can make these methods run faster?

Has anyone even encountered this issue or can reproduce it?

I should note that the actual running of the script (i.e., the `ScriptC.forEach` method) runs very fast on both devices / OS's. Also, I am using the native `RenderScript` APIs and not any support libraries.

Any input would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I copied here the relevant row from Androids Lollipop-release source code in Github of [Allocation.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/rs/java/android/renderscript/Allocation.java)

```
static public Allocation createFromBitmap(RenderScript rs, Bitmap b) {
        if (rs.getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 18) {
            return createFromBitmap(rs, b, MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                                    USAGE_SHARED | USAGE_SCRIPT | USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE);
        }
        return createFromBitmap(rs, b, MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                                USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE);
    }
```

Notice how when the target SDK is higher than 17, the Allocation is created by default with the `USAGE_SHARED` flag. Could it be that these extra flags are causing the problem? Should I be using the `USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE` flag instead?

**Edit 2**

Following [R. Jason Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819933/r-jason-sams?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=1)'s advice, I ran the following script when the Nexus 5 was connected to my computer:

```
adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1
```

After this, the runtime of the said functions is significantly faster (~30-40 millisec & 20-50 millisec respectively). Still not as fast as pre-lollipop devices, but within the accepted performance range.

My only issue with this solution is that, unless I don't understand something, cannot be considered a solution, since it would require me to call this script on every problematic device before running the app on it.

Is there anything I can do in my code which can simulate this adb call?

**Final Edit**

Okay, so it seems like the issue stemmed from the fact that I was creating a new RenderScript object on each time I called the function which performed the blend effect using RenderScript.

I did some code refactoring and now, instead of creating a new RenderScript object on each call to the effect method, I reuse the same one each time. The 1st creation of the RenderScript object still takes much longer to create on Lollipop devices, but the problem is mitigated now since I continue to reuse the same object throughout multiple method calls.

I will add this as an answer.

Comment: Has the timing of the kernel launch also changed?

Comment: You mean the time the actual rendering? no. Only the time of creating the Allocation objects and calling destroy() on the RenderScript object.

Comment: Thanks, one other thing to try.  "adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1"  That will disable the HW driver in case its the SOC driver that changed.

Comment: That VASTLY improved the performance on the Nexus 5 device running Lollipop, but I'm not sure this qualifies as a solution, since it seems I would need to do this on every device before running my app... What is the significance of this adb call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the issue stemmed from the fact that I was creating a new `RenderScript` object on each time I called the function which performed the blend effect using `RenderScript`.

I did some code refactoring and now, instead of creating a new `RenderScript` object on each call to the effect method, I reuse the same one each time. The 1st creation of the `RenderScript` object still takes much longer to create on Lollipop devices, but the problem is mitigated now since I continue to reuse the same object throughout multiple method calls.

I make sure to call `destory()` on the shared `RenderScript` object once I am sure I no longer need it to ensure there are no memory leaks.

According to [this](https://plus.google.com/wm/1/+MarioViviani/posts/fhuzYkji9zz) post, it seems that it's fair practice to reuse `RenderScript` objects rather than creating a new one each time, but I would be glad to hear input from other people regarding their experience on the matter. It's a shame there's not much documentation on this topic online, but so far, everything seems to be working well across multiple devices / OS's.

Comment: It's best to re-use the RS object.  Setting the setprop to force CPU execution speeds up context creation by skipping loading of the GPU acceleration driver.  For the same reason it reduces performance.  Loading drivers is expensive and for this reason the context should be re-used, ideally just one per process.  Treat creating and destroying them with the same care you would an OpenGL context.

Answer (score 1):

There was an Allocation Type that was added in Api 18 (USAGE_SHARED).  If you are forcing Renderscript to copy the bitmap backing memory (instead of using it in place) that might account for the difference.

```
 Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRenderContext, result, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);
```

Comment: Thank you, I can only check this on Sunday, so I'll follow up with you then.